# Bootstrap & angular 8. undefined variable in _root.scss

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular8

I tried updating my project to angular 8.0.0 today and I ran into an issue with bootstrap where I can't find a solution.

I use bootstrap 4.3.1

when I do `ng serve`, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--13-3!./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

  @each $color, $value in $colors {
                         ^
      Undefined variable.
  ╷
3 │   @each $color, $value in $colors {
  │                           ^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss 3:27  @import
  stdin 11:9                                   root stylesheet
      in ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss (line 3, column 27)
```

In my angular.json, I have this (I just included the parts relevant for scss):

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "sass"
    }
  },
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.json"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
          "./node_modules/c3/c3.css",
          "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "./src/styles/styles.scss"
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/styles"
          ]
        },
        "scripts": [],
        "es5BrowserSupport": true
      },
```

From what I understand of the error, it is due to the fact that global scss variable are not availables, in `"./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"`, it looks like this:

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "root";
@import "many_other_stuff"
```

The $colors variable is defined in `"variables"`, so it should be available within `"root"`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this Stackblitz and compare your package.json, angular.json (and other relevant files) to see if you missed installing some dependency. This Stackblitz has angular 8.0.0 and uses bootstrap 4.3.1

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkx8zp?file=package.json
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkx8zp?file=angular.json

You need to add these in package.json to install bootstrap and use scss versionof it with angular 8.0

```
"bootstrap": "4.3.1",
"jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
"popper.js": "^1.14.7",
"node-sass": "4.7.2",
```

Comment: I had these dependencies but looking at your Stackblitz, I found a dependency that I didn't have that solved the issue: node-sass. I installed it and it is working now. Edit your answer to add this and I'll accept it

Comment: I could have won the bounty on this question that you offered earlier :( . Sad that you didnt see this answer sooner

Comment: Updated my answer please check.

Comment: Hey no issues :) Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

It should be scss instead of sass :

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it didn't change anything